# ZF2 sanitize variables for DB queries

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, sanitization

In making database queries in Zend Framework 2, how should I be sanitizing user submitted values? For example, $id in the following SQL

```
$this->tableGateway->adapter->query(
  "UPDATE comments SET spam_votes = spam_votes + 1 WHERE comment_id = '$id'",
  \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass parameters when you execute..

```
 $statement = $this->getAdapter()->query("Select * from test WHERE id = ?");
 $result = $statement->execute(array(99));

 $resultSet = new ResultSet;
 $resultSet->initialize($result);
```

You can also pass them directly to the query method

```
 $statement = $this->getAdapter()->query(
    "Select * from test WHERE id = ?", 
    array(99)
 );
 $result = $statement->execute();

 $resultSet = new ResultSet;
 $resultSet->initialize($result);
```

Both will produce the query "Select * from test WHERE id = '99'"

If you want to use named parameters:

```
$statement = $this->getAdapter()->query("Select * from test WHERE id = :id");
$result = $statement->execute(array(
    ':id' => 99
));

$resultSet = new ResultSet;
$resultSet->initialize($result);
```

If you want to quote your table/field names etc:

```
$tablename = $adapter->platform->quoteIdentifier('tablename');

$statement = $this->getAdapter()->query("Select * from {$tablename} WHERE id = :id");
$result = $statement->execute(array(
    ':id' => 99
));
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I hope this isn't silly but can that array also be parameterized? `"Select * from test WHERE id = :id"`, and `array(':id' => 99)`?