# Getting Statement couldn't be produced with sql in zend2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

this is my function in my model:

```
public function user_login($getData,$session_id){ // manage the user's login 
        $email = $getData['login_email'];
        $password  = $getData['login_password'];
        $select = $this->adapter->query("select count(*) as counter from users where email = '$email' and  password = '".md5($password)."'");
        $results = $select->execute();
        if ($results->current()['counter'] == 1 ){
            $update = $this->adapter->query("update users set session_id = '".$session_id."' where email = '".$email."'");
            $update_session = $update->execute();
            return 1; 
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

When I executed the count query it works and im also using this method to get values from queries or to insert data in db. but now i want to do a simple update, which does not work for some reason. I don't know why ? why i'm getting this message ?

**UPDATE**: this is the content of the Module.php file from my module name folder:

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {

        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
    public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Application\Model\UsersTable' => function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table = new Model\UsersTable($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: But you know that you're open to SQL injections? And what error message do you get?

Comment: Look here how to secure your queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274354/zf2-sanitize-variables-for-db-queries

Comment: I;m getting this error: " Statement couldn't be produced with sql" and at the moment i do not care about injection. I just want to execute it. but for some reason it does not work and i don't know why

Comment: the problem is that i used 2 times $this->adapter, but I don't know what is wrong with that and how to make this work?? can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: This sounds like a bad statement, perhaps some non escaped characters. Try to use parameters (link that I posted) or echo out the complete insert query. `echo "update users set session_id = '".$session_id."' where email = '".$email."'";`

Comment: if i echo the query i copy pasted into phpmyadmin and it works perfectly. There is no issue with the query something is wrong with this->adapter, it does not allow me to execute multiple queries in the same function for some reason that at the moment I'm not able to undestand

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029811/zf2-already-active-query-prevents-execution

Comment: Another question: Why reinvent the wheel and not using [Zend\Authentication](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html)?

Comment: I just want to do in my own way. I got this:  Call to undefined method Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::close(): i used this code:  $this->adapter->close(); before the if

Comment: it is really weird to execute queries in zf2 , in codeigniter it was simple. For example. in zf2 i write 20 lines of code in 20 different files in ci i write 10lines of code in the same file :)))

Comment: try: `$select->getDataSource()->getResource()->closeCursor();` before the update.

Comment: @bitWorking i am using mysqli not pdo. I tried and this is the result: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Mysqli\Statement::getDataSource()

Comment: other ideeas? I;m still blocked with this :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, found solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029811/zf2-already-active-query-prevents-execution).

Probably unbuffered query?

```
$statement = $adapter->query("SELECT ...");
$result = $statement->execute();
$result->buffer();
// validate your result
```